# Why do we use sequence to expression conversion in lisp interpreters?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp

I am reading SICP which uses Scheme dialect of lisp. My question is why is there a need for sequence to expression conversion function as defined below which is used in conditional definitions but isn't used in the if expressions?

```
(define (sequence->exp seq)
    (cond ((null? seq) seq)
          ((last-exp? seq) (first-exp seq))
          (else (make-begin seq))))

(define (make-begin seq) (cons 'begin seq))
```

Following is the definition of if expression which doesn't require sequence to expression conversion:

```
(define (if? exp) (tagged-list? exp 'if))
(define (if-predicate exp) (cadr exp))
(define (if-consequent exp) (caddr exp))
(define (if-alternative exp)
    (if (not (null? (cdddr exp)))
        (cadddr exp)
        'false))

(define (eval-if exp env)
  (if (true? (eval (if-predicate exp) env))
      (eval (if-consequent exp) env)
      (eval (if-alternative exp) env)))
```

Following is the definition of conditional whose predicate does require sequence to expression conversion.

```
(define (cond? exp) (tagged-list? exp 'cond))

(define (cond-clauses exp) (cdr exp))

(define (cond-else-clause? clause)
    (eq? (cond-predicate clause) 'else))

(define (cond-predicate clause) (car clause))

(define (cond-actions clause) (cdr clause))

(define (cond->if exp) (expand-clauses (cond-clauses exp)))

(define (expand-clauses clauses)
    (if (null? clauses) 
        'false ; no else clause
    (let ((first (car clauses))
         (rest (cdr clauses)))
        (if (cond-else-clause? first)
            (if (null? rest)
                (sequence->exp (cond-actions first))
                (error "ELSE clause isn't last: COND->IF"
                clauses))
            (make-if (cond-predicate first)
                     (sequence->exp (cond-actions first))
                     (expand-clauses rest))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `if` expression can only evaluate either one *consequent* expression, or one *alternate* expression. But a `cond` expression evaluates a *sequence* of expressions associated with the conditional clause that is true. The `sequence->exp` procedure is needed to convert a sequence of expressions into a single expression. By wrapping the sequence in a `begin` form, a single expression is created which *can* be evaluated as a consequent or alternate expression in an `if` expression.

The purpose of the `sequence->exp` calls in the posted code is to facilitate the conversion of `cond` expressions to `if` expressions; consequently, any sequence of expressions found in a `cond` branch must be converted to a single expression in a newly minted `if` expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. But I am still having problem with the following: You said, _"An if expression can only evaluate either one consequent expression."_
But I am imagining something like this. 

`(if (x>0) 
(set! (x  5)) (set! (y 6)))` This has clearly 2 consequent expressions. 



Plus don't the sequence of expressions in cond expression exist already in form of a list? If not, then in what form do they originally exist before being converted to a single expression? `sequence -> exp` only seems to add just a `'begin` in front of each consequent list of cond expressions.

Comment: @BenBitdiddle -- No, an `if` expression has one consequent and one alternate expression: `(if <test> <consequent> <alternate>)`. A `cond` expression has some number of conditional clauses, each of which is a list composed of a test and a sequence of expressions: `(cond (<test> <exp1> ...) ...)` The point is, there may be many expressions `<exp1> <exp2> ...` which must be evaluated in sequence when a test evaluates to true. `if` can't handle this alone.

Comment: I don't recall the detail of how the list is constructed in SICP, but a conditional clause is _already_ a list; I imagine that `cond-actions` strips the test leaving only a list of expressions; `cons`ing `begin` onto that wraps the sequence of expressions in a `begin` form.